# WordPress redirecting after IIS reverse proxy

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, iis, proxy, wampserver

I'm setting up a WordPress site. We uses IIS reverse proxy at our main server and set a wampserver locally for the website.

The problem is that **most pages (except the *main page*) can't be accessed** through the proxy. It says `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` in Chrome (similar result in Safari).

I'm new to WordPress and not sure what happens, I guess details may be needed to find the problem:

1. The local link (local IP address, e.g.: `1.2.3.4/iac/introduction`) works for all pages.
2. Adding preview argument for all pages (e.g.: `www.sitename.com/iac/introduction/?preview=true`) make it accessable; The search page (`www.sitename.com/iac/?s=`) also works.
3. Our reverse proxy was set as follow:
   [image]
4. WordPress site options in the `wp-admin` page
   [image]
5. `.htaccess` on the `/iac/` folder

   ```
   # BEGIN WordPress
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
   </IfModule>
   # END WordPress
   ```
6. `index.php`

   ```
   <?php
   /**
    * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
    * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
    *
    * @package WordPress
    */

   /**
    * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
    *
    * @var bool
    */
   define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

   /** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
   require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
   ```
7. folder tree

I tried to put the WordPress folder in either `www/` or `www/iac/`, but neither worked.

I'm not sure what is wrong in my WordPress or proxy settings. All suggestions and advices are welcomed. Thanks!

Frank

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got an dirty answer: comment `template_redirect` related codes in   `wp-includes/template-loader.php`

Note that some minor redirect error may appear in *wp-admin*, but the main site works well.

```
//if ( defined('WP_USE_THEMES') && WP_USE_THEMES )
/**
 * Fires before determining which template to load.
 *
 * @since 1.5.0
 */ 
//  do_action( 'template_redirect' );
```

another way I found is edit `functions.php`:

```
remove_action(‘template_redirect’, ‘redirect_canonical’);
```

Seems a much clearer solution (without changing wp's main folder), but it didn't work in my case :(

Comment: To comment the do_action statement is working properly, thank you for your help @Mo Frank Hu!
(The remove_action in functions.php is not working indeed).